# ActionScript - Contact Form Not Working

Tags: php, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to debug a contact form that was built in Flash, but I'm not sure how I can go about debugging this. From the ActionScript, I can tell that it's supposed to POST the results to /assets/files/functions.php. The problem is that when I fill out the fields and click onto 'Send' (which is supposed to trigger this), nothing happens and I can't tell if it's a PHP issue or a flash issue.

Is there any ideas as to how to debug this?

The website can be [found here](http://nordicacondos.com/) and the form can be seen by clicking onto 'Connect' and then click onto 'Send Inquiry'.

The code may be seen below:

```
lvOut = new LoadVars();               //create lv object  
lvIn = new LoadVars();                //create lv object
lvIn.onLoad = function (success) {
if(success){
    gotoAndPlay("success");
}else{
    gotoAndPlay("failure");
}
}

function submit() {
if ( (inputName.text != "") && (inputAddress.text != "") && (inputCity.text != "") && (inputState.text != "") 
      && (inputCountry.text != "") && (inputTelephone.text != "") && (inputEmail.text != "") ) {
        lvOut.input_name = inputName.text;
        lvOut.input_address = inputAddress.text;
        lvOut.input_city = inputCity.text;
        lvOut.input_state = inputState.text;
        lvOut.input_zip = inputZip.text;
        lvOut.input_country = inputCountry.text;
        lvOut.input_telephone = inputTelephone.text;
        lvOut.input_email = inputEmail.text;
        lvOut.input_bedrooms = inputBedrooms.text;
        lvOut.input_realtor = inputRealtor.text;
        lvOut.input_comments = inputComments.text;

        if (realtorYes) {
            lvOut.input_hasRealtor = "yes";
        } else if (realtorNo) {
            lvOut.input_hasRealtor = "no";
        } else {
            lvOut.input_hasRealtor = "no answer";
        }       

        //send vars to functions page and load in result 
        lvOut.sendAndLoad("assets/files/functions.php", lvIn, "POST"); 
}
}

btnSend.addEventListener("click", submit);
```

Please help me out as much as possible! :-)

Comment: We might be able to help if you posted some code.

Comment: Good point. Adding the code now.. sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your flash app: it sends nothing. I just entered webpage you said with Chrome and opened "Network" tab in "Developer's tools" menu. It captured 0 requests on "send" button click. I  don't know AS2 (saveAndLoad is AS2 method), so I can't say what is wrong, but  [here](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_9/article_442-post-request-data-in-as3.htm)
is a working example of POST request in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a different approach by using `URLLoader` class. I assume your functions.php file is somewhere online.

```
const SITE_DOMAIN:String = "PUT_YOUR_SITE_DOMAIN_HERE_UP_TO_ASSETS_FOLDER";
var loader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);

request = new URLRequest();
request.url = SITE_DOMAIN + "assets/files/functions.php";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loader.load(request);

function loadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // handle load complete
}

function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
    // handle security error
}

function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    // handle io error
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your PHP script : http://nordicacondos.com/assets/files/functions.php
Fix it, then try some trace in your AS code to see what is send to PHP.

1. Check if your test on non empty values works by adding a trace inside (I think your problem is here because your swf sends nothing even if all fields are filled)
2. Check the content of the lvOut object before send, in AS2 you can browse the content like this

> ```
> for (var name in lvOut) {
>   trace(name +'->' + lvOut[name]);
> }
> ```

Add the full path to the PHP script so you can test from Flash IDE.

1. Add a trace in the lvIn onLoad handler to check if its fired

You may also check on the PHP side by logging the raw request like this :

```
$handle = fopen('log.txt', 'ab+');
fwrite($handle, print_r($_REQUEST, true) );
fwrite($handle, PHP_EOL);
fclose($handle);
```

Make sure that you have write permissions on the functions.php directory.

Of course using AS3 would offer better control... :)